# Power bounded elements of $\Bbb Q_p \langle T \rangle /(T^2)$

Tags: number-theory, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, rigid-analytic-spaces

I am rather confused by this example in [9, page 63](https://web.math.princeton.edu/%7Esmorel/adic_notes.pdf).

**Context.** Let $A= \Bbb Q_p \langle T  \rangle /(T^2)$.

$\Bbb Q_p\langle T \rangle$, which as pointed out, this is  the completion of $\Bbb Q_p[T]$ wrt to the sup norm $\sup |a_k|$.

**I would like to compute $A^\circ$.** its set of power bounded elements.

The text claims that the answer is isomorphic to$$\Bbb Z_l \oplus \Bbb Q_l T$$

I would appreciate if someone explains why. My argument below shows after that it should be
$$ \Bbb Z_l \oplus \Bbb Z_l T$$

---

1. $\Bbb Q_l\langle T \rangle$ with the Gauss norm, $|\quad|= \sup |a_k|_p$ for $f= \sum_0^\infty a_k T^k \in \Bbb Q_l\langle T \rangle $. See [8,pg63](https://web.math.princeton.edu/%7Esmorel/adic_notes.pdf),
2. we endow $A$ with the *residue norm*, $|\quad|_r$. For $\bar{f} \in A$,
   $$|\bar{f}|_r = \inf_{h \in \Bbb Q_l\langle T \rangle, \bar h=\bar{f}} |h|$$
3. An element $\bar{f} \in A$ is power bdd. iff $|\bar{f}|_r \le 1$.
4. By  this formula, we see that for an arbitrary element $\bar{f} \in A$, represented $\sum a_kT^k$, we can really just take the lift of the first two elements. $a_0+a_1T$.
   But
   $$|\bar{f}|= |a_0+a_1T| = \sup \{ |a_0|_l, |a_1|_l\} \le 1 \Leftrightarrow a_0, a_1 \in \Bbb Z_l $$

**What went wrong ? In retro spect, I think 3. is what went wrong. The residue norm doesn't seem to be power multiplicative in general.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please avoid terminology.

$\Bbb Q_p \langle T  \rangle $ is the completion of $\Bbb Q_p [T]$ for the norm $\sup |a_k|_p$ ?

You get a natural norm on the quotient by $T^2$, which is $|r+sT|_A = \max |r|_p,|s|_p$.

$A^\circ$ is the elements such that $\lim\sup_n |u^n|_A\ne \infty$.

$$|(r+sT)(v+wT)|_A=|r(v+wT)+v(r+sT)|_A\le \max |r|_p |v+wT|_A,|v|_p |r+sT|_A$$ and $|r+sT|_A^n \ge |r|_p^n$ so $$A^\circ=\Bbb{Z}_p+T \Bbb{Q}_p / [T^2=0]$$

Comment: My bad for the terminology. Yes it is completion. I was reading of Bosch's book on nonarchmedean analysis.

Comment: Quotient of a normed algebra (by a closed ideal) is a normed algebra, here the absolute value of $\Bbb Q_p \langle T  \rangle$ became a norm in the quotient.

Comment: So to check that I understand your argument correctly, you've shown in the longer inequality that $|(r+sT)^n| \le |r+sT|$, whenever $|r| \le 1$. Hence $\Bbb Z_p + T \Bbb Q_p / (T^2=0) \subset A^{\circ}$.

Comment: I don't really understand the  second inequality:shouldn't we use 
$ |(r+sT)^n|_A \ge |r^n|_p $ ? This gives the other inclusion.

Comment: If you prefer use $(r+sT)^n = r^n + r^{n-1} s T$ directly to find $|(r+sT)^n|_A$